# PHP - ICMP Ping

Tags: php, sockets, ping, php-7, icmp

So I'm trying to work out how to ping a couple of hosts reliably across multiple systems from PHP. For this I've decided the best way is to get PHP to do the ICMP ping so that I'm not using exec or similar.

My current solution (found on google) is as follows:

```
function testPing($host, $timeout = 1) {
    /* ICMP ping packet with a pre-calculated checksum */
    $package = "\x08\x00\x7d\x4b\x00\x00\x00\x00PingHost";
    $socket  = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, 1);
    socket_set_option($socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, array('sec' => $timeout, 'usec' => 0));
    socket_connect($socket, $host, null);

    $ts = microtime(true);
    socket_send($socket, $package, strLen($package), 0);
    if (socket_read($socket, 255))
        $result = microtime(true) - $ts;
    else
        $result = false;
    socket_close($socket);

    return ($result===false?2:0); // 0 = good, 2 = bad
}
```

which currently results in `Warning: socket_create(): Unable to create socket [10013]: An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions.`

I'd appreciate it if anyone could work out a fix for that error or a better way to do a ping.

Comment: Creating a raw socket (which is needed for a ping) requires root permission. Your PHP interpreter is probably not running as root--which is good. Can you use a TCP connection to port 80 instead? Another solution could be involve `exec('ping -c 1 hostname', $output, $retval)`, system calls, however, can create security issues.

Comment: @sauerburger a couple of the machines being pinged aren't serving web content, thus I can't think of a port I can reliably test, which is why I went for ping. I'm currently on Windows if that's any help with the permission issue.

Comment: OK, I assumed you were on Linux. I think you need administrator permissions also on windows to open a raw socket, however I can't test it at the moment.

Comment: Ping implementations in PHP:
1. https://github.com/geerlingguy/Ping
2. https://github.com/nyrobert/php-ping